# Configure Python to include another directory when looking for packages

Tags: python, suse

I'm on a SUSE machine where the default Python site-packages location is `/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages`. Some packages automatically install themselves in `/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages` instead. How do I configure Python so that it also looks in `/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages`?

Comment: I guess that [PYTHONPATH](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html) could do the job. Look in "6.1.2. The Module Search Path".

Comment: I don't want to force everyone to have to PYTHONPATH defined. Isn't there a way to change the default?

Comment: lorin, you can either set an environment variable (like PYTHONHOME), copy the python executable, create a wrapper script, copy the executable to a different directory, or recompile the program to use a path other than the program directory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Please correct errors and omissions as necessary. Thanks.)

First, a question and a comment. I don't use SUSE, so take this with a pinch of salt. Are the packages that install in /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages official packages? If so, SUSE is broken, so that is not likely. If they are not official packages, you could either ask the packagers to use the standard paths, or, alternatively, you could
submit a wishlist bug to SUSE asking them to support this additional path. This will save you and other people additional headaches.

For the moment, you have the following possibilities, in order of decreasing scope:

1. Change the module search path for all users (method 1)

   Change the module search path in the
   Python installation.

   The default module search path is
   hardwired into the binary. Add-on
   paths can be configured at runtime,
   for example in the site.py file.
   For example, Debian uses
   /usr/lib/python2.6/site.py (for the
   default python 2.6 installation) to
   do its site-specific configuration.
   At the top of the file is written

   ```
   Append module search paths for third-party packages to `sys.path`.

   ****************************************************************
   * This module is automatically imported during initialization. *
   ****************************************************************
   [...]

   This will append site-specific paths to the module search path.
   ```

   The Debian patch
   `debian/patches/site-locations.diff`
   says

   > For Debian and derivatives, this
   >   sys.path is augmented with directories
   >   for packages distributed within the
   >   distribution. Local addons go into
   >   /usr/local/lib/python/dist-packages,
   >   Debian addons install into
   >   /usr/{lib,share}/python/dist-packages.
   >   /usr/lib/python/site-packages
   >   is not used.

   The patch in question is

   ```
                   sitedirs.append(os.path.join(prefix,
   "Lib", "site-packages"))
                elif os.sep == '/':
       +            sitedirs.append(os.path.join(prefix,
   "local/lib",
       +                                        "python" + sys.version[:3],
       +                                        "dist-packages"))
                    sitedirs.append(os.path.join(prefix,
   "lib",
                                                "python" + sys.version[:3],
       -                                        "site-packages"))
       -            sitedirs.append(os.path.join(prefix,
   "lib", "site-python"))
       +                                        "dist-packages"))
       +            sitedirs.append(os.path.join(prefix,
   "lib", "dist-python"))
                else:
                    sitedirs.append(prefix)
                    sitedirs.append(os.path.join(prefix,
   "lib", "site-packages"))
   ```

   So you could modify the site.path in
   your system package to produce a
   modified module search path. You
   probably don't want to this, though.
   For one thing, you will have to
   merge this in on every update of
   your distribution's python package.
2. Change the module search path for
   all users (method 2)

   Add a file of the form something.pth
   to a directory that is already in
   the search path, which contains a
   path, either relative or absolute.
   Eg.

   ```
   /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages$ cat foo.pth 
   /home/faheem/dummypythonpath
   ```

   In another terminal do

   ```
   >>> import sys
   >>> sys.path
       [...,'/home/faheem/dummypythonpath',...,]
   ```
3. Change the module search path for
   all users (method 3)

   The environment variable PYTHONPATH
   is normally used to append to the
   system path at user level. You can
   put it in a file which will be
   sourced by all users. Eg. in Debian
   we have /etc/bash.bashrc, which says
   at the top

   ```
   # System-wide .bashrc file for interactive bash(1) shells.

   # To enable the settings / commands in this file for login shells as well,
   # this file has to be sourced in /etc/profile.
   ```

   So you could add or PYTHONPATH
   there. You probably want it to be
   sourced for both login and
   interactive shells, so you'll want
   to check on that. Unfortunately,
   distributions are often flaky about
   enabling this.

   The paths in PYTHONPATH are added to the default list of 
   search paths in the system (which can be obtained for
   example by sys.path - see below). Allowing for the
   possibility that PYTHONPATH is set already,
   just add desired additional directories to it, eg.

   ```
   export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:"/home/username/lib/python2.6/dist-packages"
   ```

   If you source the PYTHONPATH variable, and then check sys.path again, you will
   see the paths have been added. Note that the position in which the paths in
   PYTHONPATH are added to the pre-existing paths does not seem to be prescribed by
   the implementation.
4. Change the module search path per user.

   The usual way is to change
   PYTHONPATH in the user's bashrc,
   namely `~/.bashrc`. Again, check that
   it is sourced for both login and
   interactive shells.
5. Change the module search path on a per script basis. This
   is done by appending to sys.path,
   namely

   ```
   import sys
   sys.path.append(some_additional_path)
   ```

   This will only work for the script
   that is importing this. This is
   normally used, as far as I know, for
   casual use, when importing modules
   in nonstandard locations, like from
   somewhere in a home directory.

See also Greg Ward on [Modifying Python's Search Path](http://docs.python.org/install/index.html#inst-search-path). This has a good discussion of the available alternatives.

Comment: The packages are for openSUSE and I'm installing them on SLES. Fixing the packages is the right way to do it, but I'm still curious about the answer to the question.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`sys.path`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html):

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/home/me/mypy")
```

You can also check the [`site`](http://docs.python.org/library/site.html#module-site) module documentation, which explains how the site-specific paths are computed.